# Cannot disable hibernate on Windows : The request is not supported

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

When I try and disable hibernation as Administrator, Windows7 says :

```
C:\windows\system32> powercfg -h off
Hibernation failed with the following error: The request is not supported.

The following items are preventing hibernation on this system.
        There are one or more legacy drivers installed:
                VgaSave
        An internal system component has disabled hibernation.
C:\windows\system32> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: See if this helps....https://sundium.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/an-internal-system-component-has-disabled-hibernation/

Comment: Your title and introduction are wrong: you are trying to hibernate, not to disable hibernation, which is already disabled. The problem driver `VgaSave` is presumably associated with your graphics interface, so you should try updating all the graphics drivers. If this does not replace the problem driver, search for the latest W7 drivers for your system and install them manually. Of course, if the hardware is old, it is possible that there isn't a non-legacy update.

Comment: @AFH I don't think the hibernation is already disabled because the "hiberfile.sys" is still there

Comment: Your problem is exactly like the one I linked to, check your registry setting.

Comment: @Moab In the meantime, I finally created a new powercfg plan with no sleeping and the `hiberfil.sys` disappeared. But I guess it comes to the same thing as changing your registry key value on the current plan. Can you please convert your comment to an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "HibernateEnabled" registry DWORD, if it is not 0, then set it to 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above edit of the registry file, remove the hibernation.sys file on the next reboot.

However on my computer that path did not show the hibernation dword file but I did a control f to search and I put hibernation and found the dword file.